# Repeater is not getting client-side updated Items

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

This is code for a user control  I have a repeater which has data value attributes (`data-camera-mac` and `data-checked`).  These values will be filled on the C# side:

```
repeaterCameras.DataSource = variableName;
repeaterCameras.DataBind();
```

I have an on-click C# method which reads the Items in the Repeater fine (method `btnSave_Changes`).  Then I added some JavaScript which manipulates and shifts the HTML.  The JavaScript works fine and manipulates the front end as expected.  The JavaScript also changes the data value attributes.  However, when the on-click event happens (`btnSave_Changes`), it prints the original set of Items in the Repeater as if no change happened from the JavaScript.

**HTML:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repeaterCameras" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="<%# (bool)Eval("Checked") ? "row-fluid camera-row highlight-row highlight_selected_row" : "row-fluid camera-row highlight-row" %>" 
            data-camera-mac=<%# Eval("Mac") %> >

             <div class="highlight-bar"></div>

            <div id="divArrows" class="arrow-column camera-column-padding" 
                runat="server" visible="true" data-checked=<%# Eval("Checked")%> 
                data-camera-mac=<%# Eval("Mac") %> >
                <span id="spArrows" >
                    <i id="upArrow" class="icon-arrow-up icon-large" 
                        style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="upArrowClick(this)" ></i>
                    <i id="downArrow" class="icon-arrow-down icon-large" 
                        style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="downArrowClick(this)" ></i>
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="check-box-column camera-column-padding">
              <span id="spCheckBox" runat="server">
                <i id="cameraSelectCheckBox" 
                    class="<%# (bool)Eval("Checked") ? "icon-ok icon-large" : "icon-check-empty icon-large" %>"   
                    style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="clickCheckBox(this)"
                    data-camera-mac=<%# Eval("Mac") %> ></i>
              </span>
            </div>

       </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function clickCheckBox(element) {
    var notHighlight = "row-fluid camera-row highlight-row";
    var highlight = "row-fluid camera-row highlight-row highlight_selected_row";
    if (element.className == "icon-check-empty icon-large"){
        element.className = "icon-ok icon-large";
        highlightRow(element.getAttribute("data-camera-mac"));
    }else if(element.className == "icon-ok icon-large"){
        element.className = "icon-check-empty icon-large";
        unHighlightRow(element.getAttribute("data-camera-mac"));
    } else {
        alert("Problem:  " + element.className);//TODO:  log error
    }
}

function highlightRow(mac){
    var currentClass = "row-fluid camera-row highlight-row";
    var newClass = "row-fluid camera-row highlight-row highlight_selected_row";
    var rowsList = document.getElementsByClassName(currentClass);
    for(var i = 0; i < rowsList.length; i++){
        if (rowsList[i].getAttribute("data-camera-mac") == mac) {
            var tempElem = rowsList[i].getElementsByClassName("arrow-column camera-column-padding")[0];
            tempElem.style.visibility = 'visible';
            tempElem.setAttribute("data-checked", "true");
            rowsList[i].className = newClass;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function unHighlightRow(mac){
    var newClass = "row-fluid camera-row highlight-row";
    var currentClass = "row-fluid camera-row highlight-row highlight_selected_row";
    var rowsList = document.getElementsByClassName(currentClass);
    for(var i = 0; i < rowsList.length; i++){
        if (rowsList[i].getAttribute("data-camera-mac") == mac) {
            var tempElem = rowsList[i].getElementsByClassName("arrow-column camera-column-padding")[0];
            tempElem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            tempElem.setAttribute("data-checked", "false");
            rowsList[i].className = newClass;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function upArrowClick(element) {
    var current = element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var previous = findPrevious(current);
    if (previous) {
        current.parentNode.insertBefore(current, previous);
    }
}

function findPrevious(element) {
    do {
        element = element.previousSibling;
    } while (element && element.nodeType != 1);
    return element;
}

function downArrowClick(element) {
    var current = element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    var next = findNext(current);
    if (next) {
        current.parentNode.insertBefore(next, current);
    }
}

function findNext(element) {
    do {
        element = element.nextSibling;
    } while (element && element.nodeType != 1);
    return element;
}
```

**C#:**

```
    protected void btnSave_Changes(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("btnSave_Changes");
        if (repeaterCameras == null || repeaterCameras.Items == null || repeaterCameras.Items.Count == 0)
            return;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("repeaterCameras.Items.Count = " + repeaterCameras.Items.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < repeaterCameras.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("i = " + i);
            HtmlGenericControl div = repeaterCameras.Items[i].FindControl("divArrows") as HtmlGenericControl;
            string macStr = div.Attributes["data-camera-mac"].ToString();
            string checkedStr = div.Attributes["data-checked"].ToString();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("data-camera-mac = " + macStr + ", data-checked = " + checkedStr);
        }

    }
```

Comment: use hiddenfields with unique id and read server side picking from request form

Comment: @Infer-On Change the Repeater into a Request Form?

Comment: what you find in 'HtmlGenericControl div = repeaterCameras.Items[i].FindControl("divArrows") as HtmlGenericControl;' ? and what you find instead in the request form during post back?

Comment: @Infer-On I find the `div id="divArrows"` (which is what I want to find).  It gives it to me in the correct original order.  However, after writing some JavaScript that changes the order (and some other values), I still get the same original order.  I want the new order.

Comment: Its because you change only the rendered html, and not the repeater server side items representation, I suggest you to add an addictional order attribute and change the value client side

Comment: @Infer-On you can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the sorting of client side representation of repeater, but the inalterated sorting of items in the datasource;

This is the view state of a simple repeater:

```
/wEPDwULLTEwNjkxNzU2MzgPZBYCAgEPZBYCAgEPFgIeC18hSXRlbUNvdW50AgUWCgIBD2QWAmYPFQQQRW1waXJlIEJ1cmxlc3F1ZQlCb2IgRHlsYW4IQ29sdW1iaWEFMTAuOTBkAgIPZBYCZg8VBA9IaWRlIHlvdXIgaGVhcnQMQm9ubmllIFR5bGVyC0NCUyBSZWNvcmRzBDkuOTBkAgMPZBYCZg8VBA1HcmVhdGVzdCBIaXRzDERvbGx5IFBhcnRvbgNSQ0EEOS45MGQCBA9kFgJmDxUEE1N0aWxsIGdvdCB0aGUgYmx1ZXMKR2FyeSBNb29yZQ5WaXJnaW4gcmVjb3JkcwUxMC4yMGQCBQ9kFgJmDxUEBEVyb3MPRXJvcyBSYW1henpvdHRpA0JNRwQ5LjkwZGSThjyUMF+lfuzF5an9+yGiqSdlTXMozV4JAAW5zYmwsg==
```

Try to parse it in an online viewstate viewer like [this](http://ignatu.co.uk/ViewStateDecoder.aspx)

for this input:

[image]

the ouput will be this:

[image]
[image]
[image]

So after your client side manipulation the state of datasource will be unalterated, the simplest solution could be add an order attribute to your dataitems and change the value client side.